# apt-get sources could not be read

Tags: apt, repository

I'm using Linux Mint and every time I use `apt-get update` in terminal I receive this message.

```
E: Type 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list`?

Comment: ive deleted the repository that the error message says is the problem the only other repository that is there is: deb https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.10/main utopic main Intel Graphics drivers

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit your `additional-repositories.list` file and ensure the line for Chrome (the first line apparently) is

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

The line you currently have is missing at least the `deb` part.

Comment: how do i edit my additional repositories list files?

Comment: How did the file get there?

Comment: i tried removing it from the repository list and i still get the same error message?

Comment: Are you sure it's *exactly* the same error message?

Comment: after deleting all my aditional repositories this is the error message i get:

E: Type 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
Go to the repository dialog to correct the problem.
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.